# How to deliver a JSON object from Oracle 10 to a web service in the cloud

Tags: json, oracle, azure, web, oracle10g

I have been tasked with providing a solution to deliver a JSON object from Oracle 10 to a web service in the cloud.  I will be using PL/JSON for generating the JSON object, the problem comes with the delivery aspect of the required solution.  Is there functionality within Oracle using PL/SQL for deliver of the JSON object to the cloud (this is very much my preferred approach)?  Or will I need to resort to an external service in something like Java to provide this functionality?  Some sample code/psuedo code would be much appreciated.

PS:  I have very little exposure to web-technologies so please be gentle :-)

Regards
Paul J.

Answer (score 1):

you need use utl_http package

here's a good example of how to post json string from pl/sql to web service
[invoke-a-rest-service-from-plsql](https://technology.amis.nl/2015/05/11/invoke-a-rest-service-from-plsql-make-an-http-post-request-using-utl_http-in-oracle-database-11g-xe/)

```
begin 
  publish_cinema_event('2', -4);
end;

create or replace
procedure publish_cinema_event
( p_room_id in varchar2
, p_party_size in number
) is
  req utl_http.req;
  res utl_http.resp;
  url varchar2(4000) := 'http://localhost:9002/cinema';
  name varchar2(4000);
  buffer varchar2(4000); 
  content varchar2(4000) := '{"room":"'||p_room_id||'", "partySize":"'||p_party_Size||'"}';

begin
  req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST',' HTTP/1.1');
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0'); 
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'application/json'); 
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(content));

  utl_http.write_text(req, content);
  res := utl_http.get_response(req);
  -- process the response from the HTTP call
  begin
    loop
      utl_http.read_line(res, buffer);
      dbms_output.put_line(buffer);
    end loop;
    utl_http.end_response(res);
  exception
    when utl_http.end_of_body 
    then
      utl_http.end_response(res);
  end;
end publish_cinema_event;
```